# Using similar MySQL tables but for different varchar size of one column to save on DB size, querying via UNION

Tags: mysql

I'm creating 2 similar tables, atestunion1 and atestunion2, with columns of: of id, customer_id, product_id,  comment, date. The only difference between these is the length of the varchar comment. The "why" of this structure is below.

As comments are entered, the number of characters are counted, and then the entry is saved to the table (via if or switch php statement) with the smallest varchar character size that the comment with fit into.

Then, these are accessed like a single table, using UNION, like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM atestunion1 UNION SELECT * from atestunion2 ORDER BY date
```

This query seems to work without issue - the different comment field size doesn't seem to cause a problem - but I'm wondering if there are issues with this conceptually. The reason for doing this is to save on the DB size. I believe (assumption 1) that a comment field with 20 characters in varchar(30) column takes up less memory than one with varchar(500). However, I would think that this sort of optimization might be built into MySQL and is thus not in need of my lowly hack. Maybe it does this already, such that my assumption 1 is simply incorrect? Or, perhaps there is a setting for the varchar column that will cause this?

My waterfall of questions:

1. Does MySQL already do such an optimization behind the scenes, such that an entry with some number of characters takes up the same memory regardless of the varchar setting and such that I don't need to mess with it?
2. If not, is there a setting for the varchar that would cause it to do so?
3. If not, does this concept of similar tables but for the varchar size difference, then accessed like a single table via UNION, seem like a valid and non-problematic way to save on DB size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in storage size between `varchar(30)` and `varchar(500)` (for the same string) is **one byte**. See [String Type Storage Requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings):

> *L* represents the actual length in bytes of a given string value.
>
> [..]
>
> `VARCHAR(M), VARBINARY(M)` [..]
>   *L* + 1 bytes if column values require 0 − 255 bytes, *L* + 2 bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes

So no - It's not worth splitting the table and overcomplicating your code.

The only case I know, where it might make a significant difference, is when you use temporary tables with `MEMORY` engine. Then the `VARCHAR` columns will be expanded to it's maximum size (That are 2000 bytes for `VARCHAR(500)` with `utf8mb4` character set).

See [The MEMORY Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html):

> `MEMORY` tables use a fixed-length row-storage format. Variable-length
>   types such as `VARCHAR` are stored using a fixed length.